# HelloWorld.exe (process 12192) exited with code 0 issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm a beginner in learning C++ programming and just started to use IDE VS Community 2022.
I've created the new project corresponding to tutorial and when i run it i get the messege in the console:

```
C:\Users\??????\source\repos\HelloWorld\x64\Debug\HelloWorld.exe (process 12192) exited with code 0.
```

The code is

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

I know it's not an error, but is there some of solution to remove this message?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The message indicates the program was executed successfully. Try adding `\n` before `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the IDE you are using. Try to run your program using the command line prompt directly and the message will not be displayed.